# How can I set different parameters for two different calls to Call to Test in HP ALM

Tags: test-design, quality-center, hp-alm

I have a test template `Fill in account information` with params: `account_number`, `email_address`. The template is called in test `Legal entity registration` twice and should be called with different parameters: the first time for registration and the second time for an update (with another data).

But in `Legal entity registration`'s test configuration there are only two parameters `account_number`, `email_address` which are used in both calls...

So, how can I have test configuration like:

- `account_number_1`
- `email_address_1`
- `account_number_2`
- `email_address_2`

**The solution till now:**

is to set fixed parameters in the second call e.g.:

[image: Fixed params example]

and configuration settings only applied to the first pair of params.