# Is it possible to edit 'hard-value' parameters of 'Call to Test' in HP ALM?

Tags: test-design, quality-center, hp-quality-center, hp-alm, hp-alm-12.20

When you create `Call to Test` there is a choice to set `Actual Value` of each parameter in called test (let's name it `hard-value`). If you do not specify the value it's possible to specify it in `Test Configuration` parameters (let's name it `link-value`)

As I have told in post ['Set different params for two calls to test in single test-set'](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14340/how-can-i-set-different-parameters-for-two-different-calls-to-call-to-test-in-hp) it's only possible to use `hard-value` (as there is no answers).

Now, I need to improve my test-sets and also change several `hard-value` params.

[image]

`Edit test step` button opens call to test without any possibility to edit `hard-value` params (and to edit anything at all). And I can't see any other way of even trying to edit.

**Solution till now:** create new call to test and delete old one (it's too bad cause you have to fill in about ten params instead of editing single one)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, I have found that in HP-ALM 11 if you right click on the Call to test step there is an option in the context menu Called Test Parameters...
Clicking on the option will allow you to alter the hard values for that call to test step.

[image: d]